# Selenium is slow when opening and/or retrieving local html file

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, chromium

I am attempting to retrieve data from pro-football-reference.com, but due to their restrictions on accessing the site, if you access it too quickly, they ban you. I downloaded all of the HTML pages to a data folder on my local machine.

The issue is that now when I try to open the file using a Selenium webdriver it takes about 95 seconds to open and retrieve the html. Below is the code that I am running. The input 'box_score_file' is the local files that I have downloaded to my machine. On average files are around 500 KB.

Is this issue just due to the size of my files or is there a more efficient way to retrieve this?

```
def Parse_File(box_score_file):
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(f'file://{box_score_file}')
    html = driver.page_source
        
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select('tr.over_header')]
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select('tr.thead')]
    return soup
```

I've tried using the requests library, but since some of the tables for the html file are hidden by javascript if I use requests library I can't retrieve all of the tables that I want to create a DataFrame with.

I've also tried using playwright, but whenever I attempt to use playwright I receive the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyee.asyncio'. I've tried 'pip install pyee', but anaconda then reports back that the requirement is already satisfied. I've also tried async playwright, but that just gives me the same issue as before saying there is no module named 'pyee.asyncio'

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright, TimeoutError as PlaywrightTimeout

def Parse_File(box_score_file):
    try:
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.chromium.launch()
            page = browser.new_page()
            page.goto(box_score_file)
            print(page.title())
            html = page.inner_html()
    except PlaywrightTimeout:
        print(f"Timeout error on {box_score_file}")
        
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select('tr.over_header')]
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select('tr.thead')]
    return soup
```

This is my first time posting, so please let me know if I can provide any additional information or details and thank you for your time.

Comment: [500kb *is* quite large...] are any of the `tr.over_header` or `tr.thead` elements loaded with js? If not, then you could see if just parsing directly with `soup = BeautifulSoup(open(box_score_file, 'r'), 'html.parser')` is any better

Comment: @Driftr95 I believe that I have tried passing the html directly without opening it and that limits me to only being able to retrieve one of the tables. [link](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201509100nwe.htm) Using the example through this link. If I just retrieve the HTML using python's requests library I can only pull in the 'Passing, Rushing, & Receiving' table and if I try to obtain any of the other tables, for instance 'Team Stats' it tells me that the table does not exist. I've also tried removing the decompose statements from my code and it still does not work.